# Swift UIView.animateWithDuration disregards animation code at times

Tags: xcode, swift, animation, uiview

I'm trying to animate a UIButton to shrink and move to the view's center. This animation alternates between running correctly and not. When it doesn't run correctly, it disregards the call sending the UIButton to the center, and only shrinks the view in place.

Animation code:

```
println("before send box center \(self.box1.center) to middle \(self.view.center)")

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
     println("1 send box center \(self.box1.center) to middle \(self.view.center)")

     self.box1.center = self.view.center                
     self.box1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0001, 0.0001)

     println("2 send box center \(self.box1.center) to middle \(self.view.center)")
}, completion: { finished in
     println("final box center \(self.box1.center) to middle \(self.view.center)")
})
```

When the animation runs correctly, the first two printlns show the box's center CGPoint before the animation, and the final two printlns show the view's center CGPoint, which is now also the box's center point.

When the animation messes up, the first two printlns show the box's center CGPoint before the animation, the third println (within the animation block) shows the box's center has been set to the view's center, BUT when we get to the println in the completion block, the box has returned to its original center point (and the animation does the same, shrinking the box in place, without moving it to the center)

**What can cause this same animation code to flip between following its code and disregarding its code?**

**What can cause the code within the animation block which sets the box's center point to have been disregarded by the time we get to the completion block?**

There is no other code animating or changing the frame or location of the box I am trying to animate.

I've tried adding UIViewAnimationOptions.OverrideInheritedCurve and . AllowAnimatedContent and .BeginFromCurrentState and .AllowUserInteraction in hopes of finding a glitch causing the issue but none of those have made any difference in how the code executes or how the animation shows.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have "Use AutoLayout" checked in your Storyboard/XIB. You have to do animations differently when you use AutoLayout. Instead of changing a view's frame or center, you should add constraints for those settings and hook up IBOutlets to those constraints..

Then in your animation code change the constant value of the constraint(s). and then call `layoutIfNeeded()` on `self.view`.